# Django / Redis Paths for Celery + Cache

Tags: python, django, redis

Do I need multiple Redis paths? I'm using Celery with Redis but also django-redis for caching.

Is the right thing to do something like:

Celery:
`redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0`

Cache:
`redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1`

Or is it normal that they use the same path?

Comment: As far as I remember, Celery uses Redis to cache tasks and related data, while Django uses Redis to cache application data. As they are different, it would be better to use different paths.

Comment: @Sraw Thanks! Wasn't sure if that was the standard way to go or not.